# loop in web scraper

Tags: python, postgresql, web-scraping

The script should find the addresses of subpages with articles and collect the necessary data from them. The data should go to the database. Data should be collected by processing HTML documents.

exactly what it should: 1. find the 10 most common words with their numbers. 2. find The 10 most common words with their numbers per author. 3. posts authors with their name.

I have not finished words counter yet, but at the moment I have with two loops (2.1, 2.2) this should go into every article and get the content from them and authors names.

I get such an error:

```
UserWarning: "link/" looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client. 
You should probably use an HTTP client like requests to get the 
document behind the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup.
' that document to Beautiful Soup.' % decoded_markup
```

This is my script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://teonite.com/blog/page/{}/index.html'
all_links = []

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://teonite.com/blog/')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    article_links = ['https://teonite.com' + item['href'][2:] for item in soup.select('.post-content a')]
    all_links.append(article_links)
    num_pages = int(soup.select_one('.page-number').text.split('/')[1])

    for page in range(2, num_pages + 1):
        r = s.get(url.format(page))
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        article_links = ['https://teonite.com' + item['href'][2:] for item in soup.select('.post-content a')]
        all_links.append(article_links)

    all_links = [item for i in all_links for item in i]

    d = webdriver.Chrome()

    for article in all_links:
        d.get(article)
        soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
        [t.extract() for t in soup(['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title'])]
        visible_text = soup.getText()

        try:
            print(soup.select_one('.post-title').text)
        except:
            print(article)
            print(soup.select_one('h1').text)
            break
    d = webdriver.Chrome()

    for article_links in all_links:
        d.get(article)
        soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')

    # nie moj !!!!!!

    # 2.2. Post contents
    contents = []
    for all_links in article_links:
        soup = bs((article), 'html.parser')
        content = soup.find('section', attrs={'class': 'post-content'})
        contents.append(content)


    # 2.1. Authors

    authors = []
    for all_links in article:
        soup = bs(article, 'html.parser')
        author = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'author-content'})
        authors.append(author)



    # POSTGRESQL CONNECTION
    # 1. Connect to local database using psycopg2

    import psycopg2

    hostname = 'balarama.db.elephantsql.com'
    username = 'yagoiucf'
    password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    database = 'yagoiucf'

    conn = psycopg2.connect(host='balarama.db.elephantsql.com', user='yagoiucf',
                            password='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', dbname='yagoiucf')
    conn.close()
```

Comment: This looks wrong:  for article_links in all_links:
        d.get(article) and later on this soup = bs((article), 'html.parser') as well etc.... you keep using for loops where you don't use the actual loop variable from the current loop.

Comment: I'm sorry for such mistakes. I'm learning python and django just a few days but I have to finish this project. How can I fix it ?

Comment: See some comments below. You only need the one loop with the original selenium webdriver object. That loop over all_links visits all links. The html from each page is loaded into soup object. Grab whatever you need then e.g. author info.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous places where you are using a string generated during a prior loop instead of your current loop variable e.g.

```
for all_links in article_links:
        soup = bs((article), 'html.parser')
```

`article` is a url generated in an earlier loop (and quite possibly the source of your error)

---

Also, `all_links` is a list of links (flattened from list of lists) which now has been changed to your loop variable for `article_links`

---

At this point

```
for all_links in article:
    soup = bs(article, 'html.parser')
```

you are passing an url string to bs instead of html I believe.

---

You also re-create an instance of webdriver when you should continue with the existing instance.

---

I think you only need the one loop with selenium over the original

```
for article in all_links:
```

This visits all the blogs. You can extract whatever content you need whilst on that page within the loop.